# How to go to the location of a folder

Tags: python

I'm a really noob in Ubuntu and I want to know how to go to the location of a folder.

I recently downloaded some "Custom Themes" for my Python IDLE and I want to install them. But I don't know how to access to the Python folders.

I've read that these folders are located in /usr/bin but I don't know how to go there.

Could you please help me? Thank you guys

I have Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: I don't quite see what this has to do with python itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get to any directory you would want to use the 'cd' command like so:

```
cd /usr/bin
```

However I don't believe /usr/bin is where you would want to go if you are looking to install themes for IDLE. That is home to the python interpretor itself.

I believe you need to put it in your .idlerc directory. The path to said directory varies but it should just be in your home folder.

Here is a quick little blog post that talks about installing themes.
[IDLE themes](http://www.roguecode.net/2011/09/python-idle-themes.html)

On a bit of a tangent, if you are looking for a quick and dirty little tutorial on some of the most basic and useful commands on the linux command line I would check out [the command line crash course](http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/). Really easy way to get acquainted with the cli.

Comment: Don't mention it! Glad I could help you out.